# Php MVC module backend frontend

Tags: php, mvc

В общем, интересует следующее. Есть обычный сайт на php по принципу MVC. В нем модульная структура. У каждого модуля имеется пользовательская часть (внешняя) и админ (та что в админке). Сейчас структура модуля следующая:

```
-Module
 --frontend
  ---models
  ---views
  ---controllers
   ----ItemController.php
 --backend
  ---models
  ---views
  ---controllers
   ----ItemController.php
```

Работает, но возможно кто–нибудь подскажет более правильную/лучшую структуру?